# Permanently Turn on Super USB-C Charging ThinkVision P34W-20

Tags: laptop, display, power, usb-c

This question is probably specific to this particular monitor but hoping someone has had experience with this type of thing.

I am using the ThinkVision P34W-20 curved monitor and connecting to my ThinkPad X1 Extreme Type 20Y6 via USB-C. The default power sent over USB-C is insufficient to power the laptop, so I have to switch on Super USB-C Charging using the buttons on the monitor. The problem is the setting does not stay when I unplug the laptop and then plug it back in. I have to change the settings every time.

**Is there a way to have Super USB-C Charging permanently turned on?**

FYI, I cross-posted this question on the [Lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/ThinkVision-p34w-20-Permanently-Turn-on-Super-USB-C-Charging/m-p/5179370).